# TypeError: CheckBox is not a constructor

Tags: dojo, arcgis, esri

Getting Below error when tried to use new CheckBox({
        checked: false,
      }); in my widget.

````
    at showResults (Widget.js?wab_dv=2.12:146)
    at Object._successHandler (init.js:2313)
    at Object._handler (init.js:2307)
    at init.js:64
    at init.js:2302
    at c (init.js:104)
    at e (init.js:104)
    at n.DeferredList.resolve.callback (init.js:105)
    at b (init.js:2311)
    at init.js:2311 "TypeError: CheckBox is not a constructor
    at showResults (https://lr90q4pzw:3344/webappbuilder/apps/7/widgets/DKMtest/Widget.js?wab_dv=2.12:146:18)
    at Object._successHandler (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2313:478)
    at Object._handler (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2307:424)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please import and include `dojo/query` always while using `jimu/dijit/CheckBox`.